# How can I add data from points to a raster file?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, r, netcdf

I have a raster layer and a shape layer consisting of points. I want to add the data from my points to the raster layer as I need this format.

[image: qgis]

Is there a way in QGIS (preferably), Python or R to add data to my raster file?

EDIT: Here is the data in my shapefile
[image: shapefile_data]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by " add the data from my points to the raster layer"? Do you want to change the pixel value of the raster-based on the points?

Comment: 1. Please decide which software you want to use. 2. Your raster already has values attached. 3. What kind of values do your points have?

Comment: @Nil, sorry. I can add the attribute table of my data points. The points in my shapefile have some climate data (i.e. temperature, relative humidity etc.)  corresponding to the pixel they are centered in (see image). Can I join these attributes to my pixel?

Comment: @Erik, the software does not really matter too much. I'd prefer QGIS as mentioned as I am working with this. Does the additional information attached in the Q help?

Comment: The software matters for determining the correct answer. Currently your question is too broad by the standards of this SE. Furthermore, your request can't be done, since rasters usually contain only one information (greyscale). 3 data sets are possible (RGB), but those have to be within the range 0 - 255.

Comment: @Erik, okay that is good to know. Can I then somehow convert my points to a similar raster the same size and projection as the underlying raster layer, I have already loaded?

Comment: Yes, you can. And the "how" depends on the software.

Comment: @Erik Qgis, please.

Comment: And, should I create a new Q instead of commenting here then?

Comment: You should do some research first, since this task is rather well documented.

Comment: From your tabular data you can create an ASCII GRID (GRASS or ESRI) or an XYZ GRID for each column using Python. Those files are readable by GDAL/QGIS.

Comment: @Erik, I have looked on this platform, I only get [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108228/rasterize-shapefile-using-another-rasters-size-and-resolution), but that does not help me, as I cannot set the resolution to be the pre-loaded raster, even though the answer suggests it. Is there any other way?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html#inverse-distance-weighted-idw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes with R:

```
library(raster)
#example raster
r <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18, vals=0)
# example points
set.seed(123)
xy <- sampleRandom(r, 100, xy=TRUE)[,1:2]
# example point attribute 
v <- 1:nrow(xy)
```

Solution

```
rp <- rasterize(xy, r, field=v, update=TRUE)
plot(rp)wind1
```

In practise you may have a shapefile `file.shp` with a variable `wind`:

```
p <- shapefile("file.shp")
rp <- rasterize(p, r, field="wind", update=TRUE)
plot(rp)
```